# sql .. dynamically retrieve monthly records

Tags: sql

SQL Question...   I would like a sql query to capture monthly records dynamically

sample data:

```
PYear   PDate           PMonth
2017    2/22/2017   February
2017    1/24/2017   January
2017    1/24/2017   January
2017    1/24/2017   January
2017    1/24/2017   January
2017    1/24/2017   January
2017    1/17/2017   January
2017    1/11/2017   January
2017    1/24/2017   January
2017    3/21/2017   March
2017    3/21/2017   March
```

I would like the output to capture monthly records..Ex records only for March

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically"? That term means something specific in SQL language. Do you just need a SELECT statement? Or a stored procedure with "PMonth" as an input? Can you format your data (use four spaces to turn it into code markdown).

Comment: you are correct, I meant to say "automate" without having to make the changes to the query on a monthly basis to trigger results for each month...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple query like the following is that what you are looking for:

```
select * from myTable where PMonth='March`
```

or

```
select * from myTable where month(pdate)=3
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the data from your table for the current month. Replace "YourTable" with your table name. This assumes your PDate column is one of the date types.

```
SELECT PYear, PDate, PMonth
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATEPART(MM, PDate) = DATEPART(MM, GETDATE())
```